# Parsing HTML files with Go

Tags: html, xml, go

Is encoding/xml the best library to parse HTML table files like this one and exist some examples how to do it?

```
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<a name="Test1">
<center>
<b>Test 1</b> <table border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
  <th> Type </th>
  <th> Region </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td> <table border="0">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th><b>Type</b></th>
    <th> &nbsp; </th>
    <th> Count </th>
    <th> Percent </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody><tr>
    <td> <b>T1</b> </td>
    <th> &nbsp; </th>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#ff0000"> 34,314 </td>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#ff0000"> 31.648% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <b>T2</b> </td>
    <th> &nbsp; </th>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#bf3f00"> 25,820 </td>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#bf3f00"> 23.814% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <b>T3</b> </td>
    <th> &nbsp; </th>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#24da00"> 4,871 </td>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#24da00"> 4.493% </td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table><br>
</td>
  <td> <table border="0">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th><b> Type</b></th>
    <th> &nbsp; </th>
    <th> Count </th>
    <th> Percent </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody><tr>
    <td> <b>T4</b> </td>
    <th> &nbsp; </th>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#ff0000"> 34,314 </td>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#ff0000"> 31.648% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <b>T5</b> </td>
    <th> &nbsp; </th>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#53ab00"> 11,187 </td>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#53ab00"> 10.318% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <b>T6</b> </td>
    <th> &nbsp; </th>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#bf3f00"> 25,820 </td>
    <td class="numeric" bgcolor="#bf3f00"> 23.814% </td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table><br>
</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
</center>

  </a>
</body></html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html — first Google result for "golang html parser" ;)

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your HTML.

Strictly speaking, the only one kind of HTML which is guaranteed to be parsed by a conforming XML parser is [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/), but despite the fact XHTML once has been thought of as coming to be *the* HTML standard, it has not really taken off the ground and these days it's considered obsolete (in favor of the much hyped "HTML5" thing and all the ecosystem around it).  The basic problem with HTML is that while it looks like XML it has different rules.  One glaring distinction is that `<br>` is a perfectly legal HTML but is an unterminated element in XML (in the latter, it has to be spelled `<br/>`), and [there are a lot more differences](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#diffs).

On the other hand, your particular example looks quite XML'ish to me, so if you can guarantee your data, while being HTML, will always be a [well-formed XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed) at the same time, you can just use the `encoding/xml` package.  Otherwise go for [`go.net/html`](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html), as suggested by @elithrar, or find some other package.